# How can I trigger images reload regardless of where they're used (CSS background-image, pseudo-element, style attribute, img tag)

Tags: javascript, css, image, dom, livereload

I'm trying to set up a livereload server that reloads image assets as they change on disk. No page refresh, just the media files, reloaded.

Trouble is these assets can appear in *a lot* of different forms:

- `<style>` CSS `background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/myasset.png');`
- `<link>` CSS `background: url('http://localhost:8080/myasset.png') no-repeat 50%;`
- `style` attribute `background-image`
- `::before`/`::after` pseudo-element CSS
- `<img>` source, srcset
- `<video>` src, `<source>` srcs
- etc.

`<img>` src updates are easy

```js
var liveUrl = imgTag.getAttribute('src');
liveUrl = __addUrlQueryParam(liveUrl, '_lf', Date.now());
imgTag.setAttribute('src', liveUrl);
```

But to try to update the URL in this way for CSS style declarations, or pseudo-elements... sounds downright depressing.

Is there an alternative technique I could use to trigger asset reload universally over the entire page?

Only the URL string is known. The element where it's used is not. It would have to somehow search the DOM for the element, find the style declaration where the URL appears, and have the ability to set that style declaration to a URL with `?_lf=1493306569919` appended. Also, it may not be in the `styleSheets` because it's overridden in DevTools. So just `window.getComputedStyles`, but that's read-only. And `.getMatchedCSSRules` is deprecated and WebKit-only.

Comment: "Also, it may not be in the styleSheets because it's overridden in DevTools." - I think at some point you should stop adding requirements that complicate the task.

Comment: @the8472 This is for designers to quickly replace a live site's resources with their locally served ones. Direct copypasta in DevTools is the quickest way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) seems to have the desired behavior.

Running `live-server --wait=100 --port=80 --host=livereload .` reacts the same way as the demo in my other answer:

[image: Demo of live asset reloading feature: what works in my fork of gulp-server-livereload works in live-server too]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an API for sending an update signal to all image assets on the page. So I wrote a patch for livereload.js to slog through every element (and pseudo-elements), check the media src, and make it reload on file change by appending a query or hash string.

Here's the solution in [my fork of gulp-server-livereload](https://github.com/akaleeroy/gulp-server-livereload/commit/27576a19768ddfffaf58b199dec03e25e6f4f6bb). More details in the code comments.

It handles the following so far:

- ☑ `<style>` CSS `background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/myasset.png');`
- ☑ `<link>` CSS `background: url('http://localhost:8080/myasset.png') no-repeat 50%;`
- ☑ `style` attribute `background-image`
- ☑ `::before`/`::after` pseudo-element CSS
- ☑ `<img>` source, srcset
- ☐ `<video>` src, `<source>` srcs
- ☐ etc.

And here's a demo of it in action:

[image: gulp-server-livereload: Demo of live asset reloading feature]